# Checking a String's format

Tags: python, string, templates

I want to check the template of a string.

```
st1 = 'ABBBBBBB'
st2 = 'ABBBBA'
st3 = 'ABB'
st4 = 'BABBB'
```

I want to know if the string contain "A" and after it only "BB"
so the answer for this will be:

> st1 is True,
>      st2 is False,
>      st3 is True,
>      st4 is False

I tried with the format function but it didnt work.

Comment: _"I tried with format fucntion but it didnt work"_ - _show_ us what you tried, don't just _tell_ us

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a regular expression:

```
import re

abb_pattern = re.compile(r'^ABB+$')

def has_abb(string):
    return abb_pattern.match(string) is not None
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> abb_pattern = re.compile(r'^ABB+$')
>>> def has_abb(string):
...     return abb_pattern.match(string) is not None
... 
>>> has_abb('ABBBBBBB')
True
>>> has_abb('ABBBBA')
False
>>> has_abb('ABB')
True
>>> has_abb('BABBB')
False
```

Comment: What does the r in `r'^ABB+$'` mean? Checked the doc but could not find it.

Comment: r=raw string.
^=start of the expression.
$=end of expression.

Comment: Could you give an re example where a non-raw string would be erroneous? I never needed this until now so I'm curious.

Comment: @Callahan: `r''` is a raw string literal; it makes specifying a regular expression easier, but is not required. See [The Blackslash Plague](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague).

Comment: @Callahan: It is not needed here, but it is a good habit to get into.

Comment: I see now, the backslash plague is a good example and it is also clear why this is good practice anyway. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions.

```
import re
matched = re.match("^ABB+$", st1)
if matched:
  matched = True
else:
 matched = False
```

Run this for each of your sts in a loop or whatever and you will have a list of true false values.

Comment: Martijn's solution is more accurate since the expression should be at the beginning of the string and end the string at the same time.